# If the page 404s, then 301?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

On a wordpress site.

I'm updating the permalinks so that the posts go to /blog/title-of-post instead of right off the route.  Problem then becomes all 400+ posts that are on the site will 404.

Rather that add a 301 redirect in the htaccess file for each of these, is there a better way?

Can I set the htaccess to detect the url, and if it 404s, to instead send the traffic to url.com/blog/the-rest-of-the-title, so that it passes the same url string but with /blog/ in front of it?

Hope this is clear, please let me know if there's any questions.

Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 0):

this is possible only on apache 2.4+ . On apache 2.4 you can pass the 404 URI string to the destination url of ErrorDocument.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This example will not work on lower versions of apache as they dont understand the %{SERVER_VARIABLE}

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding!

So that line is just added to the .htacess file?

Comment: I've confirmed that I'm on Apache 2.4+, but this isn't working, just the default WP 404 page come up.  The line above is the first line of the .htaccess file.